# Making options from 0 to 100 with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to make section with options in it going from 0 to 100 when the page is open, in html is simple just type it all out :D, but i think i can do this in java script but i am not quite sure how.
Here is my html and a little bit of js code:

```js
function options() {
            var section = document.getElementById("section");
                for(var i = 0;i < 100;i++){
                    section.innerHTML = "<option value="i">"+i+"</option>";
            }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <section id="section" onload="options">
        
    </section>

    

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The example has a syntax error. `<option value="i">` should probably be `<option value="+i+">`

Comment: `<option>`s go in `<select>`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's How you can do it -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="mySelect" onload="options()"></select>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var selectElem = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
      var element = document.createElement("option");
      element.innerText = i + 1;
      selectElem.append(element);
    }
</script>
```

Here's [the working example](https://jsfiddle.net/itsanujraghuvanshi/mzg6f0ch/)

Comment: If it helps you, Please upvote and mark the answer as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`<section>` tag doesn't support `onload`.

You can check [w3schools onload event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) and [MDN: onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload), the tags support `onload` are: `<body>, <frame>, <iframe>, <img>, <input type="image">, <link>, <script>, <style>`

So you can move `onload="options()"` to `<body>` then escape the double quotes and use `<select>` instead of `<section>` as the comments mentioned.

```js
function options() {
            var section = document.getElementById("section");
                for(var i = 0;i < 100;i++){
                    section.innerHTML += "<option value=\"i\">"+i+"</option>";
            }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body onload="options()">

    <select id="section">
        
    </select>

    

</body>
</html>
```